# How to add a text automatically to an Excel cell when cells are filled?

Tags: excel, spreadsheet

In cell 'S3' I want a Status Column, I want the cells in the status column to either say Awaiting, In SC, Awaiting Quote, or Complete.

So I guess I need the cell to say 'Awaiting' when the 'F3' is blank, but when 'F3' isn't blank I need it to say 'In SC', then when 'N3' is filled in I need it to change to 'Awaiting Quote' and then finally when 'R3' is filled in I need it to change to 'Complete'.

Comment: Trademark capitalization; grammar; noise reduction.

Answer (score 0):

Your requirements aren't completely clear, but the following seems to be what you want. In `S3` enter:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(F3),"Awaiting",IF(ISBLANK(N3),"In SC",IF(ISBLANK(R3),"Awaiting Quote","Complete")))
```

The basic idea is that a sequence of requirements (where later requirements kick in under the assumption that the previous requirements are met) can be expressed by nested `IF()` functions. Note that this formula can't control the order in which users enter data, so it doesn't really express the flow of time that your question suggests. If you really wanted that then you would either need VBA or perhaps clever uses of data validation in the cells F3, N3, R3.

Comment: This Works Perfect, Thank you very much John!

Comment: Hi John, I have stumbled across a problem, my fault for not mentioning it, sometimes we have repairs back which are done under warranty and therefore do not require quotes, so the quote cell is empty. This causes a problem because even when it is 'complete' it still says 'Awaiting Quote'.

Comment: How is the spreadsheet formula supposed to distinguish a quote which is missing but needed from a quote which is missing but not needed? Perhaps you could just put "NA" (or something similar) in that slot in rows which don't require a quote?